# how to add twitter timeline to iphone app?

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, mgtwitterengine

i have already been able to implement twitter status updates using mgtwitter engine and oauth, my problem is getting the users timeline and putting it into a table view. i know i need to get the information through the twitter api and parse it to be put into a table.

i have searched the internet and can not find a clear path to what i want to do, any help would be great. i am not looking for someone to solve the problem, more of a push in the right direction with clear instructions.

thanks in advance for any help provided ;-)

i forgot to say im building an iPhone app, that tutorial doesnt look like it would work :-s

Comment: SOLVED                                                 http://www.gobuysoft.com/2010/11/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's a great series for `mgtwitterengine` by brantontreb:

[Creating A Twitter Client For OSX – Part 1](http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-part-1/)

[Creating A Twitter Client For OSX – Part 2: Displaying Tweets](http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-part-2-displaying-tweets/)

[Creating A Twitter Client For OSX – Part 3: Publishing Tweets](http://brandontreb.com/creating-a-twitter-client-for-osx-%E2%80%93-part-3-publishing-tweets/)

this should help you, its really easy.

Comment: @the_great_monkey what exactly do you mean? he is already using `mgtwitterengine`

Comment: i was meaning twitter should provide an official sdk, like facebook does =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question exactly what you want to achieve. The above answer from Choise is solid advice. though if all you want is a twitter timeline displayed in a table you could achieve this more simply with a UIWebView and a pre-built twitter aggregator. I'd recommend something like this:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/twitter-widget-doc

though I'd contact the developer first off to make sure they were fine with me using it in my application.

If you do use something of this ilk, to get it to work you need to include the .js file in the Copy Bundle resources folder in xcode. A quick google (or even search of this site) should provide the required advice. Good luck!